# Can I convert this to just use an address link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this:

```
<input id="doCheck" type="button" onclick="doCheck('temp'); return false;" />
```

Can I convert to use the address tag?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just write it thus:

```
<a id="doCheck" href="#">
```

then in your JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#doCheck').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         doCheck('temp');
    }
});
```

You could *actually* write it:

```
<a id="doCheck" href="#" onclick="doCheck('temp'); return false;" />
```

but you shouldn't, because it mixes your JS with your markup.